# Chart.js fails to load from the local file

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I am using chart.min.js to create the charts in my report.

```
<html>
    <body>
         <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;CHARSET=iso-8859-1"/>
            <title>Report - <xsl:value-of select="//sw:report/sw:starttime"/></title>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.1/chart.min.js"></script>
            ...
        </head> 
    </body>
</html>
```

However when I copy the contents of the link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.1/chart.min.js and put it inside a local file 'chart.min.js',

```
<script src="./chart.min.js"></script>
```

I see the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+2F2A  at line chart.min.js:1
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

I have tried adding type="application/javascript" or "text/javascript" with , but nothing helped.

Update:
Looks like some unexpected characters are getting added at the begining of the html file during XSLT Transformation.

```
pavankumar@pavankumar-mac Report % cat Report.html| ghead -n2
��<html xmlns:sw="https://sillywaterwalk.com/2023/XMLSchema">
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch of character sets in xml and transfer function. Once I changed both to UTF-8, it is working fine now.